# wxSmith a good way to manage wxPanel

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a project where I'd like to have many wxPanel which are displayed or hide, depending the selection of the user. All panel are on the same position, only one is displayed at a time.

On a code side, there is no problem at all. Where it gets tricky, is how to manage this with wxSmith and keep a clear view while having many wxpanel at the sample location?

One way which is really not proper is to user the wxNotebook, and then when you start the soft delete all tabs and then show the needed panel.

I have look around to try to have the panel on a "other" wxSmith window and then load it, like a class but haven't find anything good.

I'm sure, as wxSmith is really a great tool that it must have a way to do this.

Thanks for your help!

See ya

Answer (score 1):

"One way which is really not proper is to user the wxNotebook, and then when you start the soft delete all tabs and then show the needed panel."

Why not? I use that technique for [AtomWeaver](http://www.atomweaver.com), and it works fine. The plus side is that you can design each page normally on a RAD GUI builder.

I've created a class called GUI_NotebookPageData that holds a pointer to a single notebook page. Create an array of these, holding info about all notebook pages.

Then, by index, or by name, get the info of the page you want to show/hide, and use wxNotebook's RemovePage()/InsertPage() methods.

This method is specially good for having several pages shown at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's possible to use external ressources with wxSmith, then it's very simple to manage the frames.

It create a derived class from wxPanel (or other window) on a new wxSmith window, easy to manage then just required to include it on the project.